# Number of SharePoint CAL for API use

Tags: cal

We are going to purchase a third party-server software (with a web front end) that is going to connect to SharePoint using its public API and I was wondering how many additional SharePoint device CAL we will need to purchase.

When directly accessing the SharePoint web application, we obviously need to purchase one device CAL per device.

But what if the SharePoint access is not directly made via a device, but indirectly via this third-party software ? I mean: depending on the architecture of this software, it may establish one SP connection per device, or only use one SP connection that would be "shared" by many devices.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this would come under a sharepoint server for internet sites licence ? since the end result is public facing. Try giving microsoft a call to see what they say